Loss calculation for many-to-one prediction in RNN
I'm trying to implement a simple RNN-model in PyTorch for many-to-one time series prediction.
Let's say I have recorded observations from 1-7 and the design matrix is structured as:
[1,2,3,4]
[2,3,4,5]
[3,4,5,6]
[4,5,6,7]
The idea is one prediction is made based on the four previous observations, namely many-to-one prediction.
[1,2,3,4] - [5]
[2,3,4,5] - [6]
[3,4,5,6] - [7]
[4,5,6,7] - [8]
and [5,6,7,8] constitutes my sequence of predicted values.
I understand that with every data point passing through the RNN-model, a prediction is generated. My question concerns the calculation of loss for every time step.
Specifically, after the first data point, 1, passed into the model and a prediction, 1' is produced.

Does the model then looks at the prediction 1' and the target 5, then calculates a loss between 1' and 5, and prediction 2' is compared to 5 and so on.

So basically the first sequence is [1,2,3,4] and the corresponding target is [5,5,5,5]. The model calculates loss a total of 4 times, one for each pair.

Or does it let all four time steps (corresponding to data points 1-4) pass through and recognizes that this sequence of 4 data points should produce one prediction. So the model processes all three first data points 1, 2, 3 and produces predictions 1',2',3' without taking the target into consideration. It calculates the loss until after the forth prediction 4' is made, and this loss L(4', 5) somehow represents a total loss for this sequence and is then propagated backwards.

After reading a bunch of tutorials and my course text, I'm inclined to believe that for a sequence of data points [1,2,3,4] and we still have to provide that model a target [2,3,4,5] so the the model learns that 1' is a prediction of 2 (a time step forward) and 2' is a prediction of 3 and adapts to the pattern accordingly.
In this case, many-to-one prediction differs from one-to-one only in that we simply extract the last prediction and the inner workings of an RNN-model in terms of parameter-updating is the same expect for what is concretely presented in the code (input shape and such).
